# How to increase number of truncated displayed rows in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, printing, console, series

In the terminal, I have `pd.options.display.max_rows` set to 60. But for a series that goes over 60 rows, the display is truncated down to show only 10 rows. How do I increase the number of truncated rows shown?

For example, the following (which is within the `max_rows` setting), shows 60 rows of data:

```py
s = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-06-01').to_series()
s[:60]
```

But if I ask for 61 rows, it gets severely truncated:

```py
In [44]: s[:61]
Out[44]:
2019-01-01   2019-01-01
2019-01-02   2019-01-02
2019-01-03   2019-01-03
2019-01-04   2019-01-04
2019-01-05   2019-01-05
                ...
2019-02-26   2019-02-26
2019-02-27   2019-02-27
2019-02-28   2019-02-28
2019-03-01   2019-03-01
2019-03-02   2019-03-02
Freq: D, Length: 61, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How can I set it so that I see, for example, 20 rows, every time it goes beyond the `max_rows` limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html), you can use `pd.options.display.min_rows`.

> Once the display.max_rows is exceeded, the display.min_rows options determines how many rows are shown in the truncated repr.

**Example:**

```
>>> pd.set_option('max_rows', 59)
>>> pd.set_option('min_rows', 20)
>>> s = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-06-01').to_series()
>>> s[:60]
2019-01-01   2019-01-01
2019-01-02   2019-01-02
2019-01-03   2019-01-03
2019-01-04   2019-01-04
2019-01-05   2019-01-05
2019-01-06   2019-01-06
2019-01-07   2019-01-07
2019-01-08   2019-01-08
2019-01-09   2019-01-09
2019-01-10   2019-01-10
                ...
2019-02-20   2019-02-20
2019-02-21   2019-02-21
2019-02-22   2019-02-22
2019-02-23   2019-02-23
2019-02-24   2019-02-24
2019-02-25   2019-02-25
2019-02-26   2019-02-26
2019-02-27   2019-02-27
2019-02-28   2019-02-28
2019-03-01   2019-03-01
Freq: D, Length: 60, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```